# ajax performance on loading massive list from backend

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

What I did for the CRUD in my app is that I select all the item from backend and load it to the front-end and loop the item out using js, to be specified I used ajax.

Think of my app is a todo list. Even if a user inserted a new item, I suppose still need to select all the items from db again after insert query right? same goes to delete, I may use remove() but still need to load so that my item id doesn't mess up. correct?

I using angularjs ng-repeat, I cant do like id++, then I bind the the id in ng-repeat with the object that I got from json form db.

if I have 1 thousand of item that will cause problem because I trigger the load function too much in backend, how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading all the items from back end is invitation for disaster. It will kill back end and front end both. It becomes a serious usability problem if you dump 1000's of rows of data in the UI. How will the user wade through the data and act on them? Provide some way to filter the items. For example - if it is a todo list display one day at a time (default being today). For any other use case we can provide similar filtering mechanism. That way you query limited data from back end, take it to the UI and display it. If you cannot filter like this at least provide some way of pagination to limit the data you query and transport to the UI.